# Load JNA library which is shipped with jar

Tags: java, classloader, jna

I try to include a native library (a linux shared library `myLib.so`) in a java library (say `project A`) which is packaged to a jar using maven. I added the native library as resource to the jar (toplevel in the jar).

Now I try to use this library in another project (`project B`). When I call the method on my Object from by Java Library, it cannot find the library.

In project B I call something like

```
org.projectA.MyObject.initLib();
```

`MyObject` from `project A` needs to access the libarary:

```
public static void initLib() {
      MyLib lib = (myLib) Native.loadLibrary("myLib.so"),MyLib.class);
}
```

So, can I ship the shared library with my jar or do I need to use workarounds like getting the resource as a stream and write it to the filesystem first?

Comment: JNA provides methods to unpack from a jar file and write to disk.  See [`Native.extractFromResourcePath()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#extractFromResourcePath-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 2):

You have to extract it from the JAR and write it to a temporary directory first. The OS won't let you load a shared library from memory unless you write your own PE/ELF loader.